# Self hosted GitHub action running local stack in docker , Not able to access localhost:4566,

Tags: linux, docker, github-actions, localstack, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Running github action self hosted runner.
As i have private ECR repository, I am not able to do with Git hub container service.so I run the docker manually

```
- name: install docker
        run: |
           docker run -d -i -p 127.0.0.1:4566:4566 --net bridge --NAME LOCALSTACK_DOCKER $REG/localstack:3.1
sleep 60s
curl http:127.0.0.1:4566
```

Docker was running
`docker ps -a` 
Shows that docker is running.
but netstat -tuln its  not showing port 4566 is listening .

Is it possible to run shell script directly in runner machine network because after ssh   to runner machine the able to curl http://localhost:4566
Any help is  highly appreciated

Github action should run localstack docker and able to build using

```
cdklocal bootstrap
```

and

```
cdklocal deploy --all
```

its failed becuase http:/localstack:4566 not able to access